# Auto scroll page when displaying Datepicker component

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I am using ngx datepicker in my angular application. I want the page to scroll down a little when datepicker component renders enough to display entire datepicker component.
I have seen the offical date picker doc page even there the page does not scroll 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker
Also if the whole datepicker is visible than no scroll is needed. What is the best way to solve this problem ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: add a span before the datepicker tag, add `focus` or `click` listener to the datepicker tag, when the click/focus event fires, scroll to the span

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datepicker-scroll

Set a scroll to top when date picker is selected.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#datepicker').offset().top + 30 //#DIV_ID is an example. Use the id of your destination on the page
}, 'slow');
```